# What is the simplest way to handle form data and display the results?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a basic html form set up, with a variety of inputs.  I'd like to take these inputs from the form and display them inline on a new page, in their proper places within of a larger block of stock text.

For instance, the form asks you your name.  Let's say you input "John." I'd like to then display that name on a new page within a block of stock text, for instance:  "Hi John, this is your text."

There will be a number of form inputs so it doesn't make sense to use a pop-up prompt.  I realize this is a very simple question but I'm really stuck on this.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bare bones example using only Javascript:

```
<html>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()" />
<script>
function submit() {
    w = window.open();
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    w.document.write('Hello ' + name + ', this is your text' );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tremendously helpful, thank you Ronald.  It seems I am unable to upvote due to not having the requisite 15 reputation yet.  I do apologize.

Comment: That's fine.  If you're able to accept the answer by clicking on the check-mark, that will do the trick.  Also, let me know if you have any questions about the example.

Comment: All set, just tried it and I think I understand everything.  Thanks again, I'll let you know if anything else comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using jQuery that places the inputted text into placeholders in a paragraph of text. You can try a working sample here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hansvedo/D63K7/

```
<form id="info_form">
    <input id="first_name" type="text" value="John">
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Placeholder text
<div id="paragraph">Hi <span id="first_name_placeholder"></span>, lorem ipsum.</div>​
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_button').click(function(event){
        // Stop the form from actually submitting.        
        event.preventDefault();            

        // Capture the entered name and put it into the placeholder.
        var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        $('#first_name_placeholder').html(first_name);

        // Hide the form
        $('#info_form').hide();        

        // Reveal the paragraph.
        $('#paragraph').show();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks hansvedo, this is great to know how to do in jquery as well.  I'm just starting to learn it.